# Replying to Omedetou

Tags: culture, greetings

When someone tells you, "Omedetou," what are the different things you can say?

Comment: Can we have even less context?

Answer (score 5):

ありがとう。

いいえ、いいえ。

まあ、頭いいから、合格するなんて当たり前だったべちゃ。

Comment: べちゃ is from which dialect?

Comment: @Luk Dialect from Miyagi (aka Sendai-ben)

Comment: こ、こいつ…調子に乗りやがって!!

Comment: @Axioplase: Could you add the translation? I understand the first two, but the third one is not clear to non-experts like me. :D

Comment: @Alenanno: It says "Well, I'm so clever, it was obvious I would succeed".  Because the OP didn't realise that one can be told "omedetou" for so many reasons, to which there are as many answers.